# How can I pass a single string variable from a popup.js file to a seperate javascript file on chrome extension API?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

### Here is what my code so far:
**popup.js**

```
let drawCanvas = document.getElementById('but1');

let theInputColor = document.getElementById("colorPicker").value;

drawCanvas.onclick = function(undefined){
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: "canvasDrawing.js"}, function(){
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, theInputColor);
       });
  });
 };
```

### **the variable theInputColor is the one i want to pass over to my CanvasDrawing.js file as a value for context.strokeStyle**

### **CanvasDrawing.js**

```
    ....function drawLine(context, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
         context.beginPath();
         context.strokeStyle = theInputColor;
         context.lineWidth = 3;
         context.moveTo(x1, y1);
         context.lineTo(x2, y2);
         context.stroke();
         context.closePath();
          };
```

Do i need a chrome.tabs.onMessage response?

Comment: I think you can use the (chrome.storage API)[https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage] to store the variable from popup.js and access it from the CanvasDrawing.js.
Another way is to import the drawLine function on the popup.js and pass theinputColor as a parameter.

Comment: You're half way there. Not tabs.onMessage but runtime.onMessage, see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: thanks y'all. The runtime.onMessage worked for passing a variable over to my content script. 
can you pass more than one variable using runtime.onMessage?

Comment: i'm guessing i will have to use runtime.connect for multiple message passing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the reply comments i was able to figure out the solution to my problem.Although both approaches worked I found it much better to use the storage API for sending multiple messages as well.